# Как вычисляются количество шагов и элементов логических схем, т.е C(f) и T(f)?

Tags: алгоритм

Конъюнкция, дизъюнкция, логические схемы ..

Например этой схемы, которую я прикрепил ниже, его функция (x1∨x2∨¬x3∨x4∨x5)(¬x1∨¬x2∨x3∨x4∨x5)(x1∨¬x2∨x3∨x4∨¬x5)(¬x1∨x2∨x3∨¬x4∨x5)(x1∨x2∨x3∨¬x4∨¬x5)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну, эту конкретную схему я бы перерисовал хотя бы так - https://ibb.co/wYrZrw5, если не ошибся... Все ж 15 элементов вместо 28, и шагов 6 вместо ваших как минимум 9 (точнее не считал, надо аккуратно уровни расставлять, но лень...)

Comment: Можете сказать как вы насчитали 15 элементов и 9 шагов?Типо в 15 элементов входит кол-во конъюнкции, дизъюнкция и отрицания?

Comment: также можете подсказать где я смогу найти источники в которых про это все подробно расписано, я из русскоязычных источников ничего не нашел

Comment: @doboriy vecer, как правило никто не использует СКНФ для микросхем потому что нужна наилучшая эффективность, эту функцию минифицируют в МКФ или МДФ и уже тогда вычисляют количество вентелей.

Comment: Да мне это рассказывали примерно в 1984 году на цифровой схемотехнике, так что я потому и не берусь ответ писать - могу и соврать, а уж что там сейчас... Элементы - ну, пересчитайте "квадратики". Шаги? На входе у каждого проводка пишем 0. На выходе из каждого квадратика - берем максимальное значение входов и прибавляем 1. И смотрим, что получается на выходе... Вроде бы так. Ну, а как ее правильно минифицировать - не знаю, я просто карту Карно набросал. Насколько я помню 4 том Кнута, поиск абсолютного минимума операций - это задача чтоб не переборная...